# Can't get the full public key for 4.0 beta 2 assemblies

Tags: .net, internalsvisibleto, sn.exe

I'm having an issue getting the public keys for some of the .net 4.0 beta 2 assemblies so I can make my internals visible to them (gross).

Normally, I'd just pop into SN.EXE and poof I'd have them.

But instead of getting what I'd normally expect I'm getting a bogus public key, and I'm not sure exactly why.

I'm using the 64bit version of SN

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\x64>sn.exe

I'm using it against the 64bit version of the dll I'm targeting:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.21006\system.xaml.dll

and I'm getting this as my output:

> Public key is
>   00000000000000000400000000000000
>
> Public key token is b77a5c561934e089

The token is correct, but the public key is BS.  What's going on here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the ECMA public key. See http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2004/06/09/152097.aspx

Comment: Nice.  +1 for the info.  Any idea why I can't get the internals attribute working with this public key?

Comment: What happens when you use it? And why do you use it? Only framework assemblies are signed with this key, and I don't see why they would need access to internals in your code.

Comment: It doesn't work is what happens.  The reason why is a bit complex; I'm trying to keep some components out of the toolbox in WF 4.0.... essentially, its for deserialization of internal types, which the new xaml object deserializer chokes on.  Figured if I selectively made my internal types visible to some framework assemblies it might solve that issue...